# Paper-dropdown-menu and core-dropdown-overlay errors

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to include a paper-dropdown-menu element within a custom Polymer element and I am seeing the following errors:

```
Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported.
animation-constructor.js:61 Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported.
animation-constructor.js:61 Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported.
```

and also this warning:

```
core-dropdown-overlay: dropdown's offsetParent must be the relatedTarget or the relatedTarget's offsetParent!
```

The paper-dropdown-menus display fine and these errors/warnings occur when they are clicked. The code works fine when embedded in the page itself.

My page is structured like so:

```
<page-form>
  ...
  <subform-element></subform-element>
  ...
</page-form>
```

Page form is another polymer element that represents my page, and subform-element is a piece of the form which holds the paper-dropdown-menu.

```
<polymer-element name="subform-element" noscript>
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="subform-element.css">
        <div layout horizontal center>
            <paper-dropdown-menu label="Disease" layered flex>
                <paper-dropdown class="dropdown core-transition core-closed">
                    <core-menu class="menu">
                        <paper-item tabindex="0">Foulbrood</paper-item>
                        <paper-item tabindex="0">Varroa</paper-item>
                        <paper-item tabindex="0">Tracheal Mites</paper-item>
                        <paper-item tabindex="0">Other</paper-item>
                    </core-menu>
                </paper-dropdown>
            </paper-dropdown-menu>
            <paper-input-decorator label="disease notes" floatinglabel="disease notes" flex>
                <input is="core-input" placeholder="disease notes">
            </paper-input-decorator>
        </div>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

I'm seeing the errors in Polymer version 0.5.5 and Chrome 41.